# 10GHz photodetector

Tags: pcb-design, pins, photodiode, high-frequency

I am using a PIN photodiode (Eudyna ERP1402GT602L 10Gb/s PIN+TIA receiver). I superpose two unmodulated lasers. When I try to observe their frequency response (sweep from 0-10GHz). There are dips (ups and downs). Can you please suggest how to make it more smoother. What could be the reason for it? 
Is it because of the PCB ?

Further information added: 
My setup: I have two Turnable laser sources controlled from computer. Laser1 (Current freq. 193.3550 THz, Grid:50GHz, Ch. Nr. 34, Optical pwr. +8.10dBm, Freq. Shift 0 to +5 Ghz). Laser2 (Current freq. 193.3450 THz, Grid:50GHz, Ch. Nr. 45, Optical pwr. +13.5dBm, Freq. Shift 0 to -5 Ghz). Than there is a 3dB coupler that combines these two lasers. After that we have optical power attenuator (it outputs -12dBm). Which goes to this photodiode and I than connect it directly to Spectrum analyzer without any cables.

I sweep like I change the freq. shift of both lasers. One towards 0 to +5GHz and laser2 towards 0 to -5GHz in steps of 0.05 GHz. (total 100 steps). This is how I attain the upper (red) graph. I select MAX HOLD on spectrum analyzer. and the peak starts to move towards right as the freq. shift increases. (the peak you can see at the right most point at 10GHz freq shift right now.)

I have also tested two other photodiodes (made by earlier students/teachers/i don't know. They have flat output freq. shift response over the 0-10GHz. ) On left bottom corner you can see it's output picture. 
[image: Sweep from 0-10GHz as described above. My PCB and Photodiode , on right I have laser1,2 characteristics and at bottom a comparison with another photodiode.]

Comment: If the lasers are unmodulated how are you doing the frequency sweep?  Where are you injecting the signal?  How are the two lasers superposed?

Comment: Is this photo for one laser source or for two (combined)? Is your plot similar for both one and two sources?

Comment: 2 lasers of similar wavelength might produce interference patterns that make things problematic? Also, a link to the data sheets would help.

Comment: You're trying to observe the interference signal when you mix the two laser beams? What are the red and purple traces in your graph measuring?

Comment: @KevinWhite I have two Turnable laser sources controlled from computer. Laser1 (Current freq. 193.3550 THz, Grid:50GHz, Ch. Nr. 34, Optical pwr. +8.10dBm, Freq. Shift 0 to +5 Ghz). Laser2 (Current freq. 193.3450 THz, Grid:50GHz, Ch. Nr. 45, Optical pwr. +13.5dBm, Freq. Shift 0 to -5 Ghz).

Than there is a 3dB coupler that combines these two lasers. After that we have optical power attenuator (it outputs -12dBm). Which goes to this photodiode and I than connect it directly to Spectrum analyzer without any cables.

Comment: @KevinWhite I sweep like I change the freq. shift of both lasers. One towards +5GHz and laser2 towards -5GHz in steps of 0.05 GHz. (total 100 steps). This is how I attain the upper (red) graph. I select MAX HOLD on spectrum analyzer. and the peak starts to move towards right as the freq. shift increases.

Comment: @glen_geek The bottom (dark line) shows current graph with total freq. shift of 10 GHz (laser1 freq. shift : +5GHz , laser2 freq. shift: -5GHz). 

The upper red line I attained by starting from 0GHz freq. shift. and selecting MAX HOLD on the spectrum analyzer and the peek start to move towards right side as I increase the freq. shift in steps of 0.05GHz. Soo uper line (red is attained by total 100 steps)

Comment: @Andyaka These two lasers are combined using the 3dB coupler. I got the data sheet from my Professor. The Photodiode I am using is ERP1402GT. It's from Eudyna company. It says confidential. Its data sheet just have some electrical/optical properties,absolute maximums, and some mechanical features. Nothing more. 

On internet I have tried alot but couldn't find anything related to this device.

Comment: @FahadRaza, please edit your question to include this important information. Future readers should be able to understand the whole question without reading comments.

Answer (score 2):

> There are dips (ups and downs). ... What could be the reason for it? Is it because of the PCB ?

The dips and peaks repeat roughly every 500 MHz in your frequency domain plot,

That suggests you're looking for a feature in your design that has an electrical length of about 0.3 m (so that one round trip through it takes 2 ns).

This could be the cables connecting your PCB to the spectrum analyzer.

But I think it's more likely it's happening in the optical part of your system. If one of the optical fibers in your system is about 20 cm long, look there first. My first guess would be that the fibers between your laser and the combiner is about this length. In this case, back-reflections from the fiber end can feed back into the laser and change its output power.

As a quick test, bend a fiber tightly once or twice around your thumb to create a crude attenuator. If the ripples in your SA plot change, you've probably found the source of your problem.

> Can you please suggest how to make it more smoother.

If the root cause is back-reflections into the laser, you need to reduce the back-reflections that are getting back to the laser. If you have not been careful with the type of fiber termination you use, this could be easy to fix. You'd just get the fiber re-terminated with a higher-quality finish, for example APC ("angled physical contact"), and be sure to use the same termination type for all fibers you mate it with.

If you're already using APC or UPC fiber terminations, and still need to reduce back-reflection, there are a few more steps you can take:

- Replace butt-coupled fiber connections with fusion splices
- Anti-reflection (AR) coatings on the fiber facets
- Add an optical attenuator in-line with the output fiber (but then be careful not to introduce new back-reflections at the input to the attenuator)
- Add an optical isolator in-line with the output fiber.

Probably your laser manufacturer has already used one of these methods to reduce this effect, and you're just seeing the residual after most of it has been dealt with. In that case your best solution might be to choose a different laser, for example using an isolator rather than an attenuation for this purpose. That will, however, likely cost more than what you have now.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the information. 
Actually my this PCB is directly connected to the spectrum analyzer without any cables.

Comment: I think this has something to do more with the electrical part because I have two other photodiodes (in lab made by some old students for their experiments). I have connected their Photodiodes at the end of my setup. Both of them have flat freq. response. Like freq. response amplitude does not change. it remains constant for all the freq. shift from 0-10GHz. 


Other thing is as this is HF circuit & very small components (0402 size) everytime I change solder and try to make it more clean the freq. response changes a little bit. 

So do think more clean/fine soldering will improve it ?

Comment: It is possible there's an electrical issue --- that photodiode package looks pretty beat up, for instance. But it's also possible, for example, that Eudyna changed the design of the PD since the "old students" made their circuits, and changed the optical behavior. Or that your photodiode is damaged somehow that changes its optical properties. A scratch on the fiber facet, for example.

Comment: Surely it could still be optical if there is a significant back-reflection from this diode but not the others.  What is the length of the fibers between the lasers and the coupler and the coupler to the PD?